# Find field with specific key in Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In my c# project I use [Json.net Library](http://json.codeplex.com/).

 I have long Json with many subfields, for ex:

```
{
"count": 10,
"Foo1": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Name1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Name3"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Name4"
    }
],
"Foo2": [
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Name3",
        "specific_field": "specific_values1"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Name3",
        "specific_field": "specific_values2"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Name3",
        "specific_field": "specific_values3"
    }
],
"Foo3": [
    {
        "id": "7"
    },
    {
        "id": "8"
    },
    {
        "id": "9"
    }
]
}
```

And I need to get List of all `specific_field` (id 4-6), but cant deserialized json to object, because `Foo1`, `Foo2` ... changed dynamically.

I want to know, is this possible to get values of `specific_field` when i have only json?

### I think, I found solution:

```
            var list = new List<string>();
            var result = ((JToken)json);
            foreach (var res in result)
            {  
                    list.AddRange(from foo in res.First let ret = foo["specific_field"] where (dynamic) ret != null select foo["specific_field"].ToString());
            }
```

In comment, provide, what do you think about it?

Comment: Json.NET has a Linq to Json functionality that you could use for this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use dynamics:

```
string json = "your JSON string comes here";
dynamic deserializedValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var values = deserializedValue["Foo2"];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(values[i]["specific_field"]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. But in this time I don't know name of "Foo2". I need another way.

Comment: What do you know then? As you can from my example the `"Foo2"` string could be a variable which is dynamically known only at runtime. If you don't know that you could also loop through the values.

Comment: Yes, I can loop value "Foo2", but I wantn't, because in my json I have 100+ "Foo's". I want to get access to subfield without getting values of each "Foo". I have long json and name of specific field - and thant all, what I want to use. If it's impossible, only provide it. Thanks

Comment: You cannot access subfield without first getting reference to the parent field. You will have to find a way to reach the parent first. Don't forget that any JSON serializer (be it JSON.NET or not) builds an object tree. And as you know from OOP, in order to access some child property you need to have reference to the parent first.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helpful comment. And what do you think about finding "specific_field" by handle (manually parse Json string)?

Comment: Manually parsing JSON string? No!

Comment: )))) @darinSimitrov, I know, that you answer will be that!

Comment: I update my question (add one of solution's). What do you think about it?

Comment: Throwing and catching exceptions could be slow especially if the JSON file is very large. You'd rather test if the `specific_field` field exists in the current `JObject`. That would be the only improvement I would make to your code.

Comment: Why do you have a try/catch in your loop? My previous remark about the performance still stands.

Comment: Realy, in real project I have array of 'specific_field's, and a couple of another conditions, and my linq became very fearful))